# How to fix ActionView::Template::Error (Infinity) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm noticing a strange error in my production application logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Infinity): /path/to/page/with/problem
/myapp/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/core_ext/float/rounding.rb:16:in `round'
/myapp/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/core_ext/float/rounding.rb:16:in `round'
/myapp/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/core_ext/float/rounding.rb:14:in `round'
/myapp/current/path/to/file/with/problem.rb:106:in `my_buggy_method'
```

In the code there is something like this:

```
def my_buggy_method
  (number1 - number2).round(2)
end
```

I don't have any insight as to what numbers are triggering this error. How can I refactor my code to avoid this error?

**Update:** I managed to start up a Rails console in production and track down the values that are being used in the method above:

```
number1 == Infinity
number2 == 0
```

**Update:** Upon further investigation, number1 is returning `Infinity` because of division by zero:

```
number1 == 113 / 0.0
```

Now that I know where this `Infinity` is coming from, I will add a check to make sure I can never divide by zero.

Comment: can you print the value of *number1* and *number2* ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just posted an update with the numbers I found

Comment: that's the reason.. hope you got it now..

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this error was due to trying to `round` or display `Infinity`. I did not expect this number, so I have added extra checks to make sure that I don't create `Infinity` by dividing by zero.